# How is the Hardware address mapped to eth0/eth1 on a Linux(Ubuntu) machine.?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-14.04, nic

What goes behind the hood when i add a new NIC card to my Ubuntu machine.?
Which program/module is responsible for mapping the HardWare address of the device to a name(eth0/eth1). Where are this mappings(HWaddress1-eth0, HWaddress2-eth1) actually stored.?

Comment: What do you mean by "HWaddress1"? This is not how things work. The loaded drivers find a device and they simply name them one by one. Typically by some builtin name suggestion, though that can be overridden. Not all network devices are named `ethxxx`...

Comment: Hey, i meant the hardware address of some device. Since we use names(like ethxxxx) to deal with the NIC cards, i am curious to know where actually these mappings(address to name)are stored.

Comment: What sense does that comment make? It only repeats what you already wrote. As said above: the hardware address is not relevant for the naming of the devices.

Comment: The hardware (MAC) address is burned into ROM on the NIC. Most OSes/drivers will allow you to use your own MAC address in place of the hardware address.

Comment: The answer to this question is too broad for this small space.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the kernel itself will name the nics depending on the order they are connected to the bus. This behavior is very similar to SCSI/SATA naming.

Take a look at the output of

```
lspci
```

You should find the corresponding network card there. The first column e.g. `0000:00:03.0` contains the following information:

```
0000 : PCI domain (each domain can contain up to 256 PCI buses)
00   : the bus number the device is attached to
03   : the device number
.0   : PCI device function
```

(source: http://prefetch.net/articles/linuxpci.html)

under /sys/bus/pci(_express)/devices/ you will find links that match to the lspci output. When you enter the folder of your network card, there are lots of files and folders.

You can do a find and grep

```
cd /sys/bus/.../devices/0000:00:03.0/
someuser@somemachine:/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:03.0$ find -type f -exec grep 'ethX' /dev/null {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

where ethX is your device name to get an output like

```
./virtio0/net/ethX/uevent:INTERFACE=eth0
```

(in my case a virtual machine with a virtio device)

Since this information is derived from the running kernel I bet you will also find the hardware-address there.

Happy grepping!